# Green's Theorem for $ \int <2y^2 + \sqrt{1+x^5} , (5x-e^y)> dr $ where $ C: x^2+y^2=4 $.

Tags: calculus, integration, greens-theorem

Use Green's Theorem to evalutae

$$ \int <2y^2 + \sqrt{1+x^5} , (5x-e^y)> dr $$

$$ C: x^2+y^2=4 $$

C is positively orientated

$$ \int \int (dN/dx - dM/dy) dA $$

$$ = (5 - 4y) dA $$

$$ \int \int_0^2 (5 - 4y)) r drd(\theta) $$

$$ y=r\sin(\theta)$$

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 (5r - 8\sin(\theta)r)) drd(\theta) $$

Evaluating inside integral =

$$ \int (10-16\sin(\theta)) d(\theta) $$

with a region between $0$ and $2\pi$

Evaluating this outside integral $= 20 \pi $

I was just hoping if someone had the time they could check if my setup and integration was correct, particularly in switching to polar coordinates. Thanks :)

Comment: It seems like you need to parametrise your vector field first

Answer (score 1):

Everything is right, but you missed an extra $r$ on the second last integral. It should be
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 5r - 4r^2\sin(\theta)\, drd\theta\\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{5}{2}r^2-\dfrac{4}{3}r^3\sin(\theta)\bigg|_0^2 \,d\theta\\\
& = \int_0^{2\pi} 10-\dfrac{32}{3}\sin(\theta)\, d\theta\\
& = 20\pi.
\end{align*}

Comment: @MyGlasses You are absolutely correct!